# Partial curl modal stop / start actions

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I stop and start actions when using a partial curl? I tried the functions `viewWillDisappear` and `viewWillAppear` in my current view controller but they didn't seem to be called when I switch to the settingsViewController and back.

I also tried this in my `first VC`

```
    TwistmAppDelegate *AppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    AppDelegate.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(resetSpin:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
```

And this in my `second VC`:

```
TwistmAppDelegate *AppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[AppDelegate.timer invalidate];
```

but this also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What's a partial curl?

Comment: It's a modal view like in the maps app of apple. (when you tap in the right bottom corner. ( storyboard -> Storyboard segue -> Transition)

Comment: Oh OK, I'd never heard of it before.